# How to set values to dynamically created variables in the view

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html

I'm banging my head toward the wall for this :

I want to set the value of **dynamically generated view variables from controller**
In my view template:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,value) in educations" >
    <p ng-click="loadEducation(value)">Dynamically add html to the below <div> </p>
    <div ng-bind-html="eduiframe_value[ID]"></div>
</div>
```

In my controller:

function :

```
    module.controller('listeducations',function($scope,$http,$rootScope,$cookies,ServiceEducation){
    /*
    service below will set the view variable educations
    each object contains the following :
    $$hashKey: "object:132"
    ID: "440"
    title: "HIPPA_SERVER_CONFIGURATION_1.pdf"
path : "http://stackoverflow.com/"
    */
     ServiceEducation.getEducations($scope);

     /*Open a education item in the iFrame*/
    $scope.loadEducation = function(obj){
        var p = 'eduiframe_'+obj.ID;
        $scope.p = '<iframe src='+obj.path+' >'; //but this is not working
    }

    });
```

Explanation : I want to insert a iFrame in to individual div element.

Any one has any idea how to do this ?

Comment: have u tried $compile provider , here it is  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: how does this HTML and this controller relate to each other? the HTML is iterating over an object, and displaying some value that doesn't relate to the object, and the controller has a single function that doesn't look like it's ever executed.

Comment: This should help u http://jsfiddle.net/leeroy/6j4Lg/1/,

Comment: @Claies  I wrote only the partial code of the controller ?

Comment: well, we can't answer the question if you don't write the portions of the code *that go together*

Comment: also, the fact that you only wrote part of the controller code doesn't explain what this code is supposed to even do; again, the item you are trying to display in the `ng-repeat` isn't even related to the object you are repeating over.

Comment: @shushanthp Thanks for the fiddle but I'm getting problem in using the dynamically generated variables **eduiframe_value[ID]** I can not assign it some value from controller.
Need more explanation?

Comment: @Claies yes this works..I've seen it in another stackoverflow question.

Comment: can you try to edit the question and explain what the `eduiframe_value` array is, where the `ID` you are passing is coming from, how it relates to the object you are iterating over in the ng-repeat?  It looks like you want to have multiple variables on `$scope`, and try to find each one, but it's still definitely not clear.  You can say all day that you want a dynamic variable, but you aren't showing anything but *random* variables that don't relate to each other here.

Comment: ok, now I can see where you are calling the `loadEducation` function, but you *still* aren't explaining what `eduiframe_value` or `[ID]` are; they definitely aren't in the JavaScript.

Comment: actually, now the code makes less sense; you iterate over an object, split it into key/value pairs, pass the value to a function, then in the function try to refer to the value like it was an object with another property on it, which is again another property not listed anywhere else.

Comment: ok, so now we are getting somewhere; next, why are you using `euiframe_` in one and `eduiframe_value` in the other?

Comment: and since value is your actual object, instead of `[ID]` you probably want `value.ID`.

Comment: :( String eduiframe_ is the prefix and adding value[ID] will make it  eduiframe_1 , eduiframe_2 ... and from the controller I'm trying inserting a Iframe into individual <div> element ...

Object value has ID and path property in it.

Comment: no, you can't mix syntax like that.

Comment: @Claies I'm looking for right way..

Comment: angular isn't going to know that you want to replace *just* the `value[ID]` portion of that statement

Comment: I'm trying to help, really I am, but really working through comments isn't ideal.  We've spent more time trying to just get your question into a sensible state than actually trying to address the issue.

Comment: you can't expect angular to know that `eduiframe_` isn't a variable but that `value[ID]` is.

Comment: sorry I tested my answer, and it didn't work the way I was thinking it should.